# Speed up the execution time

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I've got a task to speed up the execution time of this script. Target is below 12 secs.
The code does the job but it's not really efficient. How can I improve it ?
I suspect I'm not using the multiprocessing module the best way possible here:

```
import multiprocessing, datetime
from time import sleep


def queue_time(customers, num_of_tills):

    if len(customers) == 0:
        return 0
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    for x in range(num_of_tills):
        for y in customers:
            process = multiprocessing.Process(target=sleep, args=(y,))
            process.start()
            process.join()
    result = datetime.datetime.now() - start
    return result.seconds
```

**SUGGESTED EDIT:**

```
import multiprocessing, datetime
from time import sleep


def queue_time(customers, num_of_tills):

    if len(customers) == 0:
        return 0
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    for x in range(num_of_tills):
        for y in customers:
            process = multiprocessing.Process(target=sleep, args=(y,))
            process.start()
    process.join()
    result = datetime.datetime.now() - start
    return result.seconds
```

Please assume that the `customers` argument is a list of integers.

Comment: You're waiting for completion of a process immediately after launching it, which kills parallelism. Move `process.join()` outside of loops. It might also be a good idea to limit number of concurrent processes, e.g. by using process pool. Finally, a question: are processes CPU or IO bound?

Comment: The idea is to use all available concurrent processes (tills) to spread waiting time across all processes / threads (customers waiting to be checked out).

Comment: I may need to read up on the process pool.